# Advice on studying mathematical biology

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, reference-books, applied-mathematics, biology

I am really passionate about theoretical and quantitative biology and I would like to build my future career around this topic.
I've just got my bachelor's degree in biology (ecology) but scince I've had only one math class through the years, my math skills are very poor, so I have problems in understanding even simpe models. 
My main interests are population dynamics, adaptive dynamics and game theoretical models of social conflicts.

I would like to improve my skills, but I have just no idea where/how to start. What kinds of math should I try to focus on learning to get where I want to go?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding what would be the ideal path to a career in mathematical biology, not about teaching mathematics. I'm not sure where in the SE network it could belong, possibly Math.SE or Academia.SE, but not here on MathEducators.

Comment: By the way, I do wish you success and that you figure out a great headstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you want a course of study in applied, as opposed to pure, mathematics.

Such courses would include probability and statistics. Also "engineering mathemetics" such as differential equations, which studies the interaction of various parties in an ecosystem.